# Partial Problem from configuration settings in `$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`

Tags: python, django, django-models, pipenv, django-shell

#### Tree Directory:

```
.
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── README.md
├── Strawberry
│ ├── init.py
│ ├── pycache
│ ├── asgi.py
│ ├── settings.py
│ ├── urls.py
│ └── wsgi.py
├── catalog
│ ├── init.py
│ ├── pycache
│ ├── admin.py
│ ├── apps.py
│ ├── migrations
│ ├── models.py
│ ├── static
│ ├── templates
│ ├── tests.py
│ ├── urls.py
│ └── views.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── foo.py
├── manage.py
└── requirements.txt

7 directories, 19 files
```

Dudes, it's Ok when I use:

```
$manage.py check
```

And I get the result without any problems, Errors and Exceptions.

But when I write the same with `django-admin`:

```
$ django-admin check
```

I get Error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Strawberry'
```

From this result we can now know that Django finds/see environment variable — `$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` but don't see directory with settings.

But if I import `models` from `catalog.models` into `foo.py` then on run by python3 pipenv interpretator (Note: virtual environment is activated):

```
$ python3 foo.py
```

I get:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings
```

In this case Django not see `$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`, but `$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` has been created (in virtual environment) and its value is:

```
$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=Strawberry.settings
```

### Summing up, I want to know:

This is Ok when I execute a file (foo.py) contains x code/script that uses (imports) Django objects (models) using python interpretator:

```
$ python3 foo.py
```

I get an Error, but at the same time, when executing the same code x in django shell:

```
$ python3 manage.py shell < foo.py
```

I get the result, without any errors or exceptions.